# How to get API gateway url in Environment variable in Serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am working on a serverless framework(cloud formation), I have created two stacks in the same AWS region, and each serverless.yml(stack1, stack2) having their own APIs. How can I get the stack-1(yml) API URL in stack-2 yml.

```js
Stack-1(serverless1.yml)

functions:
  tGateWay:
    handler: src/handlers/tGateWay.handler
    name: ${self:provider.stage}-tGateWay
    environment:
      first: ${self:provider.stage}-firstlambda
    events:
      - http:
          method: any
          path: /tGateway
          private: true
```

```js
Stack-2(serverless2.yml)

functions:
  tModule:
    handler: src/handlers/tModule.handler
    name: ${self:provider.stage}-tModule
    environment:
      find: ${self:provider.stage}-find
      T_GATEWAY: https://xxxxxxxxx.execute-api.xxxxxxx-1.amazonaws.com/dev/tGateway
```

In that T_GATEWAY I want to access stack-1 API gateway URL

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have tried Export and import, but it is giving No export named <name> serverless error.

Comment: Can a brotha get an upvote with that accepted answer? 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SecretsManager and you can import it from there into your function with something like this:

```
iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - secretsmanager:GetSecretValue

functions:
  handler.js
  myHandler:
    handler: myHandler
    environment:
      yourSecretKey: "{{resolve:secretsmanager:secretYouCreated:SecretString:yourSecretKey}}"
```